# How to combine two List PropertyModels to one model in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

Let's say I have an entity called `E`.

Its structure has two fields:

```
E {
   List<A> a1;
   List<A> a2;
}
```

Currently I have two `PropertyModels` like this:

```
PropertyModel<A> a1Model = new PropertyModel(e, "a1");
PropertyModel<A> a2Model = new PropertyModel(e, "a2");
```

I have one repeater, and I want to give it one listModel only.

My current way to achieve this is to make like this:

```
List<A> aItems = new ArrayList<A>();
aItems.addAll(a1Model.getObject());
aItems.addAll(a2Model.getObject());
PropertyModel<A> aModel = new PropertyModel<A>(this, "aItems");
```

I now miss connection to database, since `e` is actually given inside a `LoadableDetachableModel`. When `e` changes inside that model, the value does not automatically flow until the field.

I am not sure does it make it now either, but somehow interfering the play with models only smells bad to my nose. Now I have only list a1 in field, and now I am adding a2.

How to achieve one model for the field (it is actually another panel)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might create a Model that combines both models to `List<E>`:

```
IModel<List<E>> listModel = new LoadableDetachableModel<List<E>>() {

    public List<E> load() {
        return Arrays.asList(a1Model.getObject(), a2Model.getObject());
    }

}
```